# How do I create an asynchronous task with uwsgi/gevent/flask that uses the request context?

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, gevent

I'm trying to access the flask request object in a spawned Greenlet. Here's the code:

```
import gevent
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/async')
def async():
  gevent.spawn(do_async)

  return 'OK'

def do_async():
  html = render_template('async.html', args=request.args)
  print html
```

When I hit the server, the first line in do_async() throws this error:

```
RuntimeError: working outside of request context
```

How do I allow do_sync() to "work outside of request context"?

Things I've tried:

- Using `with app.app_context():` in various places
- Creating a new request object and passing it as a parameter to do_async() using
  `req = app.request_context(request.environ)`
  This throws the error
  `AttributeError: 'RequestContext' object has no attribute 'args'`.
- Copied the request object with the `copy_current_request_context` decorator. This works
  but it then becomes blocking. The response isn't sent until do_async finishes even
  though it's in a gevent thread.

Software versions:

- python 2.7.5
- uwsgi 2.0
- gevent 1.0.1
- flask 0.10.1

**Edit:**

Here's something I just noticed while I was trying to "unblock" the `copy_current_request_context` decorator. Here's the code:

```
import gevent
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask import copy_current_request_context

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/async')
def async():

  @copy_current_request_context
  def wrap_do_async():
    do_async()

  gevent.spawn(wrap_do_async)

  return 'OK'

def do_async():
  gevent.sleep(0.001)    # Added to 'unblock' copy_current_request_context
  html = render_template('async.html', args=request.args)
  print html
```

Without the `gevent.sleep(0.001)` line in do_async(), the function works, but blocks (on the "real" do_async() code I'm simulating here it blocks for about 8 seconds). With the line, the  function doesn't block but the request is now empty.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to return `async.html` content to the user? If so, you can't because `'OK'` would be returned already. Have you looked at [streams](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/)?